# Why am I getting this error on the emulator when trying to change a ListView cell height?

Tags: android, android-listview

My following code works on my API 21 device.
However it does not work on the Nexus 7 API 19 emulator in Android Studio:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_cell, parent, false);


    customView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(cellWidth, cellHeight + 20));
    customView.requestLayout();


    return customView;
}
```

The exact lines that is causing this problem is the following (when I take out these 2 lines I do not get any error on the emulator):

```
customView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(cellWidth, cellHeight + 20));
customView.requestLayout();
```

Here is my error message:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: john.smith.johnsmith.testapplication, PID: 1649
                                                                               java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1826)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: everything is written in the stacktrace - you're using wrong type of LayoutParams

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams`

Comment: try changing RelativeLayout.LayoutParams with AbsListView.LayoutParams or try using getLayoutParams and modifying it instead of creating a new one Also your requestLayout() call looks unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change `Relative.LayoutParams` to `AbsListView.LayoutParams`:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_cell, parent, false);


        customView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(cellWidth, cellHeight + 20));
       //remove  customView.requestLayout();


        return customView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Weird how it doesn't cause an error on 21 :S